# Has anyone used the excellent Date.js library inside node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Has anyone created a commonjs wrapper for Date.js? 
I'd like to use the Date.js library inside node and don't want to import it as a bare file and eval it if I can help it.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard... just add a couple exports and rename it. Or you could just let it change the Date prototype...

Comment: What do you mean "import as bare file and eval"? It's just JS so it should be able to run as is on node. I imagine they aren't doing anything browser specific in the code.

Comment: They aren't. I ran it through node and it worked just fine. Just a little refactoring and it should work like a charm.

Comment: .. which part of this are you asking? Or are you procrastinating? Just do it, and see what doesn't work.

Comment: @jcolebrand, I was being quite dumb about the require syntax doing
var dt = require('./date.js'); then var d = new dt() --> errors.
Wasn't clear that date.js extends the Date prototype - doesn't return an exported object.  Answers here set me straight - so thanks to all.  I'm a JS newbie and have still not internalized prototype based inheritance so got tripped up there.

Comment: What functionality are you looking for? If eg. Date.js hasn't been made to work well with Node.js, then chances are that it's because something else has replaced it - if you tell your use case, then you could get better suggestions on alternate solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by a 'commonjs wrapper'? This code worked fine for me:

```
require('./date');

console.log(Date.today().add(5).days());
```

Date is a global object, and when you do the require, date.js modifies the global object. It didn't seem to mess up the regular date stuff.  I would personally want to refactor it, because modifying the global object seems a little scary to me.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I should try it again - I got some error messages when I did that - and assumed there was a namespace clash.

Answer (score 32):

I wrote a date library similar to DateJS that doesn't modify the `Date.prototype`. You may want to use that instead if you're worried about modifying the native Date object.

It handles parsing, manipulation, and formatting, as well as timeago and i18n.

```
npm install moment
```

Documentation at http://momentjs.com/docs

Comment: Note from the authors of moment.js: "_we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward_" ([source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Date.js and having it augment the built-in Date object which is working fine.

Turns out extending the native Date object as a new object isn't that easy (see [How to extend the Javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075231/how-to-extend-the-javascript-date-object/6075511#6075511)).

Comment: The statement about "working fine" is not entirely true: `new Date().toString()` returns `"RangeError"` (tested in Chrome)

Comment: I switched to XDate a while ago and am happy with it; Date.js is now old and unmaintained.  XDate doesn't augment the Date object but is still very easy to use: http://arshaw.com/xdate/

Comment: Ah, I noticed that the error is caused by loading DateJS after it was previously loaded (by a different plugin). After loading once, it works fine. Thanks for recommending `XDate`, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Using npm:

`$ sudo npm install -g datejs`

datejs@0.0.2 /usr/lib/node_modules/datejs

└── vows@0.5.9