# Will Function.prototype.bind() always be slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, v8, spidermonkey, late-binding

I am writing an open source javascript library, and I use `.bind()` method heavily, because I have an idea that object-oriented code looks more clear then. (*debatable, though*)

**Example**

A1:

```
var that = this;

setTimeout(function () {
    that.method();
}, 0);
```

vs

B1:

```
setTimeout(this.method.bind(this), 0);
```

**Or, a more practical code portion**

A2:

```
remoteDataSource.getData(function (a, b, c, d) {
     obj.dataGetter(a, b, c, d);
})
```

vs B2:

```
remoteDataSource.getData(obj/* or prototype */.dataGetter.bind(obj));
```

I use a non-native `bind` for older browsers, and everything went perfect until I opened a [jsperf benchmark for bind](http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-setup/3).

It looks like code using `bind` is 100 times slowlier. Now, before to rewrite all my library, I have a question for those who are familiar with javascript engines:

**Is there a probability that, being a new feature, `bind` will get optimized
 soon, or there is no chance because of JavaScript architecture limits?**

Comment: Found a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656106/why-is-function-prototype-bind-slow

Comment: And one of the best solutions is: http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-emulate/6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, fixed jsperf http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-emulate/13.

=You should not recreate static functions inside the benchmark. That is not realistic because in real code static functions are only created once.

You can see that `var self = this` pattern is still about 60% faster. But it requires the function definition to be inlined where as you can bind from anywhere and therefore have better maintainability.

---

Well no, the built-in bind semantics are ridiculously convoluted.

When I bind, I just want this:

```
function bind(fn, ctx) {
    return function bound() {
        return fn.apply(ctx, arguments);
    };
}
```

If I wanted to pre-apply arguments or use some deep constructor black magic, I would want a totally different function for that. I have no idea why any of this was included in bind.

<rant>Btw, the same problem is with almost anything introduced in ES5, punishing the common case by forcing implementations to handle some theoretical edge case that is not plausibly relevant to anyone in practice. The next language version is continuing on the same path.</rant>

The emulated bind doesn't even try to emulate bind at all. And even if you try to emulate it, you will not be able
to do it completely so that's just not fair.

So with everything else equal* the built-in bind cannot be faster than common sense custom bind which just binds.

*In JITs user code has no significant disadvantage to built-in code. In fact both SM and V8 implement many built-ins
in Javascript.

Comment: Today running the test in Firefox shows `.bind()` to be fastest but slowest in Chrome. You made lots of good points, but the conclusion the built-in bind cannot be faster doesn't seem right. While a bound function does have certain overhead, it also eliminates some overhead. In particular, it doesn't need to call into a different function, but rather shares the body of the original function, so it's very close to invoking the original. Nor does it need to traverse the variable scope to get the values it bound. So I think it'll always come down to implementation detail more than spec.

Comment: Sorry for the comment on the old answer, but someone made reference to it.

Comment: Looks like native bind is fast these days: https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-2019

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Amazing optimizations by the Chrome devs.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, late 2013, the best possible solution will be implementing **handmade** versions of `Function.prototype.bind` and either override the vendor's "native" (not being truly native) method with your own javascript code, or use your own `myBind`.

`Function.prototype.apply` is rather fast, and Array slicing, concating and shifting is slow,  so you better use `apply` instead if `bind`, or minimize arguments manipulations in `myBind` function. That will leave you without the features of parameters pre-filling.

So I see no need in rewriting everything back to closures (ugly `var that = this;`). Let the functional nature of javascript win.

More details and working code examples here:

http://jsperf.com/function-bind-performance/4

http://jsperf.com/function-bind-performance/5

http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-emulate/4  ..  10.

Summarizing: workarounds found are not so bad. Use them bravely. If you use not fully featured `bind`, don't go too far from original conception as I have found no reasons it's not implemented in C yet. It's a question of time.

Comment: Still use closures in bottlenecks