# In JavaScript loops, how are block-level allocations managed in memory?

Tags: javascript, memory, v8

I am curious about the way JavaScript interpreters manage block-level variables like `let` and `const`.

Say I have a loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const square = i * i;
}
```

Where exactly are `i` and `square` being allocated?

I understand that there is a frame stack; that each function call adds a new dictionary-like object representing the function's lexical context. When a function exits, we decrement a stack pointer. This means that we can run functions with variables without creating garbage on the heap.

But where are our block variables? Do we augment the frame stack with another item? Are they 'flattened' onto the context but with a special flag or symbol to differentiate them from variables in sibling blocks?

Finally, where can I generally learn how JavaScript interpreters (like V8) manage memory?

Comment: _"where can I generally learn how <...>"_ Probably in whatever [documentation there's available about V8.](https://developers.google.com/v8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some great stack overflow answers that might help you.
[Memory allocation for JavaScript types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970509/memory-allocation-for-javascript-types) 
[How variables are allocated memory in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800463/how-variables-are-allocated-memory-in-javascript) 
[JavaScript variables declare outside or inside loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

And of course the [documentation of V8.](https://developers.google.com/v8/) 
I hope reading these will help you understand more about javascript memory management.