# Why do plugins often avoid proper privatisation of functions?

Tags: javascript

Often I see in plugins the use of an underscore to signify a function is private, yet still allow public access (see below for an example). But why? We can either use .call, .apply or .bind for controlling the "this" keyword, or alternatively use the "self" pattern which according to this question is 60% quicker: [Will Function.prototype.bind() always be slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895305/will-function-prototype-bind-always-be-slow)

Is it lazy programming or am I missing something?

Private function exposed example:

```
var simplifiedPlugin = function() {
    this.name = 'simples';
    this._privateFunc = function() {
        console.log('Why am I here?');
    }
    this.publicFunc = function() {
         // stuff, then
         this._privateFunc();
    }
}
var pluginInstance = new simplifiedPlugin();
```

Using the self pattern:

```
var selfSimplifiedPlugin = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.name = 'self is also simples';

    function _privateFunc() {
        console.log('Nobody knows am I here');
        //I can use self instead of this
    }

    this.publicFunc = function() {
         // stuff, then
         _privateFunc();
    }
}

var anotherInstance = new selfSimplifiedPlugin();
```

So, my point is with the self pattern, the private function can still use the this context, you just have to use self.fn() instead of this.fn()

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's just a coding standard so you can easily identify what's private (or meant to be).

Comment: You *could* be super stringent about keeping private stuff actually private, but is there a massive benefit to that over just saying "functions with a leading underscore are private" in your docs? It's more a matter of taste than anything.

Comment: What you did there with 'self' is unnecessary and actually I don't think it'll work. As written, the public function could directly call '_privateFunc()'

Comment: But with other languages that allow private keywords it's frowned upon to make functions/methods that should be private public, so IMO this is the same thing. Paul I fixed that as yes I should have revised before clicking submit! George - this question is more "why aren't the functions actually privatised" than just indicating they are

Comment: a sidenote: the [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is designed to supersede the "self" pattern. it captures `this` via lexical scoping, so inside the arrow function `this` is always the same value — the value it had where the function was defined.

Comment: Interesting read thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason I would do it this way is easier debugging.

From what I've seen current JS debuggers aren't great at inspecting closed-over symbols, especially when the compiler's managed to optimise the closure well.

With the underscore convention you can still reliably access these 'private' functions when the times are tough, while the underscores make it obvious that they're only *intended* for internal use.